# I am using ngClass to change color & text on a button click & Data is fetched from Remote Server using Data Tables

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

The problem here is when I am click activate or deactivate it is getting activated for all entries how to make that function call for unique row.

HTML IS AS FOLLOWS :

```
<button [ngClass]="{'btn-danger':user.active, 'btn-success':!user.active}"
          (click)="click()"> {{text}}
    </button>
```

TS IS AS FOLLOWS :

```
user = { active: true };
    text = "Deactive";

  click() {
    if (this.user.active) {
        this.user.active = false;
        this.text = "Active";
    } else {
        this.user.active = true;
        this.text = "Deactive";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you create a sample with https://stackblitz.com ?

Comment: OK i will create & share link

Comment: added answer based on your input , or stackbiz hlep if you provide and answer below not work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution

use  `{{user.active ? 'Deactive':'Active'}}` for display value.

I have create a demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/i-am-using-ngclass-to-change-color--text-on-a-button-click--dat?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

> Component.ts

```
users:Array<any>=[{
    id:1,
    name:'User 1',
    active:false
  },{
    id:2,
    name:'User 2',
    active:true
  },{
    id:3,
    name:'User 3',
    active:true
  },{
    id:4,
    name:'User 4',
    active:false
  }]
```

> Component.html

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>
            <button [ngClass]="{'btn btn-danger':user.active, 'btn btn-success':!user.active}" (click)="user.active = !user.active"> {{user.active ? 'Deactive':'Active'}}
    </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Bro Its worked for me. Now i will manipulate as i want

Comment: What about further process as in TS then i need to perform several actions if he clicks active. I then need to send data via http & change the database values as well show alerts.